# How to create an array in JSON?

Tags: c#, webrequest

How can I post an HTTP request like this? I tried to make something like this, but I don't know how to make the `[]` section. Thanks for help!

```
{
  "ID": 1,
  "calls": [
    {
      "number": 702061966,
      "duration": "00:02:21",
      "date" : "2020-11-26 12:45:00"
    },
    {
      "number" : 123456789,
      "duration" : "00:15:48",
      "date" : "2020-11-27 08:23:00"
      },
      {
      "number" : 123456789,
      "duration" : "00:09:33",
      "date" : "2020-11-28 16:02:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is JSON. And the the `[ ... ]` signifies an array (or a list, if you prefer) of items. You should go and learn JSON syntax from a tutorial if you're unsure. And yes, you can send this kind of data using C#. Usually you'd get a C# object with an equivalent structure (defined by its properties) and serialise that to JSON using a ready-made serialiser library. Sometimes, classes which are designed for making HTTP requests (such as HttpClient) can handle the serialisation for you automatically, and you can simply pass in your C# object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a structure to represent the data in C#. For the given JSON this may look like so:

```
public record MyRequest(int ID, IEnumerable<MyItem> Calls);
public record MyItem(int Number, string Duration, string Date);
```

Now you create the request

```
var req = new MyRequest(1, new List<MyItem> {
  new MyItem(702061966, "00:02:21", "2020-11-26 12:45:00"),
  ...
});
```

... and send it

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJson("some/url", req);
```

Code examples are intended as a first orientation and not tested. You can read more about it here:

- Records: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types
- HttpClient: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0
- PostAsJson(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-5.0
- JSON: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

> I dont know how to make [] section

Any collection (`IEnumerable<>`, `List<>`, ...) will serialize to JSON list.

Notes:

- Code examples use c# 9 features
- You may want to use other data types than strings e.g. `DateTime`